# bash script with background process

Tags: bash, background, jobs

I have the following in my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ ! -S ./notify ] && find ./stylesheets/sass/ \-maxdepth 1 \-type f \-regex '.*/[^_][^/]*\.scss$' | entr \+notify &
```

what `entr` does here, is creating `notify` as a named pipe.

[ **insert** ]

```
while read F; do
            ...
            #some processing on found files 
            #(does not matter for this question at all)
            ...
done < notify
```

The problem is, first time I run the script, it sees there is no `notify` pipe, so it creates one, and puts
the process into the background.

But then the following `while` loop complains it cannot find `notify` to read from.

However, when I run script immediately after that, so for the second time now, it continues normally the rest
of the program (`while` loop part).

How would I fix this, so it runs all good as a whole?

**EDIT**:

if I put into [ **insert** ] placeholder above,

```
    sleep 1;
```

it works, but I would like a better solution for checking when that `notify` **fifo** exists, as sometimes it may need more than 1 sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always poll for the named pipe to be created:

```
until [ -p notify ]; do read -t 0.1; done
```

If you don't specifically need to maintain variables between runs, you could also consider using a script rather than entr's `+notify`. That would avoid the problem.

Comment: how does this work? I can see that while script is running there is `notify`, as soon as I `CTRL-C` the `notify` file disappears.

Comment: should I change that test condition `-S` to `-p` also at the very beginning of the script?

Comment: `-S` checks for a socket, so yes. I don't know how your `notify` pipe gets cleaned up. This code is not responsible for that.

Comment: you helped me twice tonight, I owe you a beer :)